# why Recusrsive modular exponentiation not equals iterative?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

I have implemented a non-recursive modular exponentiation

```
typedef long long uii;
uii modularExponentiation(uii base,uii exponent,uii p)
{
    int result= 1;
    base = base % p;
    while( exponent > 0)
    {
        if (exponent % 2 == 1)
           result = (result * base) % p;
        exponent = exponent >> 1;
        base = (base * base) % p;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and another one is recursive

```
uii modularExponentiation(uii base,uii exponent,uii p)
{
    if(exponent == 0)
      return 1;
    int res= modularExponentiation(base,exponent/2,p);
    if(exponent%2 == 0)
        return (res * res)%p;
    else
        return ((res*res)*(base%p))%p;


    return res;
}
```

but the two code doesn't produce the correct result. The iterative code from Wikipedia gives the correct result. What have I done wrong in the recursive version, and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: on which case does the recursive solution fail?
Try replacing ((res*res)*(base%p))%p; with ((res*res%p)*base)%p;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the usage of `int res` instead of `uii res` is the problem there are chances of overflow. Moreove even `((res*res)*base%p)%p` can cause overflow .

Improved code :-

```
uii modularExponentiation(uii base,uii exponent,uii p)
{
    if(exponent == 0)
      return 1;
    uii res= modularExponentiation(base,exponent/2,p);
    res = (res*res)%p;
    if(exponent%2 == 0)
        return res;
    else
        return (res*(base%p))%p;

}
```

Comment: Your improved code works, But I have know idea how, can you explain? The int part was not the problem.

Comment: I basically did what you did, Is the cause of the overflow is not saving the (res*res)%p in memory?

Comment: @Unbound the int part was the problem because when you do res*res then if res is int then it consider it as int multiplication hence if two large int values are multiplied it causes overflow but long long res will multiply two long long hence no overflow

Comment: @Unbound even res*res*base%p can cause overflow